# Grid data disappears when columns are grouped

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo grid to display an inline editable list of events inside of an AngularJS directive.  The data is loading and displaying as expected and everything seems to be working correctly.  I am able to sort, edit, update, and delete the data and this all works perfectly.

When I attempt to group by any column, the data disappears.  The grouping headers appear correctly with the correct data but all of the rows show up completely empty. The edit and delete buttons are in place for each row that should have data.  I can click delete and it will remove an empty row.  If the edit button is clicked text boxes appear with the correct data that was loaded from my service.  If I update the data and click update, it returns to being invisible.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Here is special-events.directive.js:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('specialEvents', [specialEvents]);

    function specialEvents () {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: link,
            templateUrl: 'app/components/special-events/special-events.html',
            controller: SpecialEventsCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'specialEventsVM',
            scope: {
                source: '='
            }
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
        /* directive controller */
        function SpecialEventsCtrl($scope, $http){
            var vm = this;
            var id = 0;

            vm.source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: function(options) {
                        $http.get('http://localhost:8181/ping').then(function(response) {
                            id = response.data.length;
                            vm.gridData = response.data;
                            options.success(response.data);
                        });
                    },
                    update: function(options) {
                        options.success(options.data.models[0]);
                        console.log(options.data.models[0]);
                    },
                    destroy: function(options) {
                        options.success(options.data.models[0]);
                        console.log('Row #' + options.data.models[0].id + ' deleted');
                    },
                    create: function(options) {
                        id++;
                        options.data.models[0].id = id;
                        options.success(options.data.models[0]);
                        console.log('Added ' + options.data.models[0] + ' with an id of ' + options.data.models[0].id);
                    }
                },
                batch: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: 'id',
                        fields: {
                            id: {editable: false, type: 'number'},
                            eventName: { type: 'string' },
                            description: { type: 'string' },
                            dates: { type: 'string' },
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
})();
```

And here is special-events.html

```
<div id="grid" kendo-grid
    k-data-source="specialEventsVM.source"
    k-height="350"
    k-groupable="true"
    k-sortable="true"
    k-pageable="{
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5 
        }"
    k-columns="[{
            field: 'eventName',
            title: 'Event Name',
            width: 200
        }, {
            field: 'description',
            title: 'Description'
        }, {
            field: 'dates',
            title: 'Dates'
        }, {
            command: ['edit', 'destroy']
        }]"
    k-editable="{'mode': 'inline', 'create': true, 'update': true, 'destroy': true}"
    k-toolbar="['create']"
></div>
```

and here is the data:

```
var data =  
                [
                    {id: 1, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 2, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 3, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 4, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 5, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 6, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 7, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 8, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 9, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 10, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 11, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 12, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 13, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 14, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 15, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' },
                    {id: 16, eventName: 'Wedding', description: 'people getting married', dates: '11/02/2014 - 11/03/2015' }
                ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue where grouping functioned the exact same way you have described.  I was using KendoUI with AngularJS as it appears you are.  I was able to fix the issue by simply upgrading to telerik.kendoui.professional.2014.3.1119.commercial from an older commercial version.  It seems like this must have been a bug with Kendo, but I haven't been able to find anything definitive in their docs about it.  It cost me a few hours or work trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.

======
Update for anyone in the future that encounters this: 
This is a bug with DataSource in KendoUI when used with angular.
http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q2-2014-sp1

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I had given up on this and disabled grouping.

Comment: Upgrading may have caused other issues for us, but while trying to figure those out we stumbled upon the docs that confirm this was a bug with DataSource.  
http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/q2-2014-sp1